# HD insight Spark retrieve message from event hub getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/eventhubs/ConnectionStringBuilder$ error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, azure-eventhub

I am trying to setup a connection to an event hub to retrieve messages,I am able to run it in Jupyter notebook provided in azure hdinsight portal. While trying to setup the same in intellij am getting below error.

> ERROR: Job state is dead ERROR: Diagnostics:  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$4.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:721)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.spark.eventhubs.ConnectionStringBuilder$   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 7 more

Code sample is provided below

```
    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.eventhubs._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark._
object SparkStreaming_Event {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("StreamEvents")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(10))
    val connectionString = ConnectionStringBuilder("Connectionstring").setEventHubName("Name").build
    val ehConf = EventHubsConf(connectionString)
      .setStartingPosition(EventPosition.fromEndOfStream)
      .setMaxRatePerPartition(10000)
    val stream = EventHubsUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ehConf)
    stream.print()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Any idea what I am missing here, I could see the jars under external libraries.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, Answering my own question.

Though we have provided the dependencies in our build tool, We would need to upload the corresponding jars in Azure to make them available for Hdinsight cluster.

1.Upload the jars in blob storage(Associated with hdinsight)

2.Provide the blob path in run configuration of hdinsight in IntelliJ Idea in the spark jars field as below.

wasb://clustername@blobaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/foldername/jarfile.jar

Hope this help some one.